Searching isn't working in aggregation lookup pipeline
So i have two collection one is favourite and another is users table where is talent added. and query searching isn't working. can anyone help me on this please
const list = await FavouriteModel.aggregate([
      {
        $match: cond,
      },
      {
        $project:{
          userId: 1,
          talentId: 1,
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "talentId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "talentId",
          pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: ["$fullName",  new RegExp('^' + search, 'i')]
                  },
                },
              },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "venues",
                localField: "homeVenue",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "homeVenue",
                pipeline: [
                  {
                    $project: {
                      venueName: 1,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$homeVenue",
            },
            {
              $lookup: {
                from: "masters",
                localField: "profession",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "profession",
                pipeline: [
                  {
                    $project: {
                      labelName: 1,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
            {
              $unwind: "$profession",
            },
            {
              $project: {
                fullName: 1,
                profileImg: 1,
                profession: 1,
                homeVenue: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$talentId",
      },
    ]).catch((err) => {
      reject(err);
    });

inside lookup pipeline i have added regexp to match with full name. and it'll start searching as soon as user search. need a help on this please. Thanks in advance

Firstly try to make pipeline and push your code according to condition to the pipeline array,
you can use this approach


 if(search){
      pipeline.push({
          $match:{
              "talendId.fullname": {$regex: search, $options: 'i'},
          }
      })
  }



This is not to run here but just for your understanding.
